# How would I add 4 buildings to a WAN

Tags: cisco, networking

As you can tell im new to networking.

I have created this LAN template for one building. The other 3 building's topologies are similar. The buildings are located in the same city.
https://gyazo.com/c78883f0d56b6a2ce09502fe97810d37
Can someone help me understand the theory behind how I would connect these 4 buildings together to be on the same network? Would I simply add another router to each building which will connect them. Or would I use the WAN emulation Cloud-PT in cisco packet tracer to connect the 4 buildings?

Apologies, I'm aware how I've worded this is probably infuriating for experts. Like I said I'm new.

Comment: What mechanism are you planning to use to interconnect the buildings?  Dark fiber?  Wireless?  Carrier managed services (L2 / L3)?  Internet VPN?  This generally comes down to underlying questions of cost/feasibility/basic requirements.  The specific hardware (and its configuration) tends to fall out from these decisions.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into tunneling. Maybe use a Site to Site VPNs.

Check this pdf out. Give it a good read. It is kinda of lengthily but it should give you the basics of connecting multiple sites together.

[Managing Site-to-Site VPNs: The Basics](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/security_management/cisco_security_manager/security_manager/4-1/user/guide/CSMUserGuide_wrapper/vpchap.pdf)